# How to set width of text marks in vega-lite / altair (text wrapping and line break) for long text

Tags: visualization, timeline, altair, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to display text over time using altair (vega-lite), which works fine using a layered chart, where one is created using the alt.Chart().mark_text() function to display the text.
The text though is multiple phrases and should be wrapped (with line breaks). How can this be done?

(I do not want to use fixed line breaks, e.g. \n, at distinct positions since the text wrapping should work with zooming too)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but you can specify a character on which to break to a new line. When zooming, the text stays the same size, so it should always fit the view.

For example making a new line for every word:

```
.mark_text(lineBreak=' ')
```

Comment: Not really what I want, I rather need to display multiple phrases of text. Having a look at the vega-lite documentation and vega-editor example (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/text.html), this does not seem to work without explicit line breaks given in the actual text.